# eclipse 4.9 is totally unusable due to languageserver not initialized after 10s

Tags: eclipse

Just trying to Open Implementation popup or (text) find goes off into "Not Responding".  Upon finally returning (seemingly years later), it just freezes again.
By the way, I am not running, nor have anything installed Spring-related.  I've also manually started the Language Experience Service on my Windows 10 (HP) laptop.

```
    LanguageServer not initialized after 10s

     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
     at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
     at 

org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.getServerCapabilities(LanguageServerWrapper.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.getLSWrappers(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.getLSPDocumentInfosFor(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.documentLink.DocumentLinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(DocumentLinkDetector.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3561)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)


     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

     eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
     java.version=1.8.0_181
     java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
     BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
     Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
     Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
     org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


     This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\..\.metadata\.bak_0.log
     Created Time: 2018-11-30 19:20:56.657
```

Comment: The Windows 'Language Experience Service" is unrelated to the LanguageServer mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Open implementation of what? Please note, [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) is not only used by STS4. By default, the _Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers_ 2018-09 is not shipped with LSP4E. So the error is caused by a plugin you have installed. What is listed in _Window > Preferences: Language Servers_?

Comment: howlger,  Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna) has a Ctrl hoover (shortcut keys) popup that displays Open Declaration, Open Implementation, and Open Return Type ... I was attempting to get the same in 4.9.  I was lucky enough to stumble upon the languageServer error after several hours, how in the heck do I figure what plugin is probelmatic?  I'm seeing Camel LSP Server for XML and   Camel LSP Server for Java.  There is no associated language server content-type with the Launch Configuration.

Comment: I finally see another error in the log that may provide a clue:  java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 24: file:/C:/webappslogs/zzz downloads/eclipse/installer/eclipse/../../../../../Users/myusername/.p2/pool/plugins/com.github.camel-tooling.eclipse.client_1.0.0.201809120921/libs/camel-lsp-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) is quite old while LSP and the Apache support based on it are very new. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the space from the path has has seemed to solve my immediate  eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745 problem. (Although my [old] Luna installation on a different machine has always had the space and it runs smoothly.)

Comment: I appear to have the same issue. In what file can you change the path?

Comment: Moving my installation dir to C: resolves the issue. Probably caused by the space in `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Don't use windows path's, for anything - save you a lot of trouble
`c:\apps` is the way to go

Comment: Few years later - the same shite with Eclipse STS 4.17.0.RELEASE.
App dir: `E:\app\sts`; workspace dir: `E:\eclipse-workspaces\java`