# Eclipse not responding on startup

Tags: java, git, eclipse

For some reason this evening I can't launch my Eclipse anymore? I don't know what to take from these logs, as I am not that experienced with Eclipse. Any help will be highly appreciated! The log from Eclipses .log file when it freezes on startup to "not responding":

I don't know what to take from these logs, as I am not that experienced with Eclipse

````
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Calgary'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2020-10-07 01:52:01.676
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1957)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2092)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.declaration.OpenDeclarationHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(OpenDeclarationHyperlinkDetector.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
!SESSION 2020-10-08 01:41:14.347 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=13.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fi_FI
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product```
````

Answer (score 1):

That looks similar to [issue 545447](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545447) affecting [LSP4E](https://wiki.eclipse.org/LSP4E), the project includes the necessary code to integrate any language server (conforming to the [Language Server Protocol specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol)) or Debug Adapter (conforming to the [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node)) in the Eclipse IDE.

It is supposed to be fixed with lsp4e 0.10.0.

Try and see if the issue persists when downloading (for testing) the [latest Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
(Upgrade from your current 4.15.0.I20200305-0155 to a current Eclipse 4.17 2020-09)

Check also [if there is any space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597575/6309) in the paths involved by your Eclipse workspace.